# Does bereavement leave cover all family deaths?

Tags: time-off, death, asia, malaysia

Last Saturday, my grandmother passed away. It really makes me sad and I will not doing my best work when I return to work. I had to help with all the funeral arrangements, and it tires me. Also, I'm still mourning her death.

So, I would like to apply for bereavement leave for three days. I tried to message to my manager to apply for bereavement leave but he stated that I'm not eligible to apply. He mentions that the bereavement leave is only for the death of parents and siblings. I need to apply for my emergency leave instead but not bereavement leave.

As I know, isn't bereavement leave cover for all family deaths?

Comment: Is there perhaps a legal precedent for you if your grandmother was your legal guardian, or if no-one else is physically capable of handling the funeral arrangements? Do you know if anyone else in the company before you has ever been allowed compassionate leave for a relative that wasn't their parents or siblings?

Comment: @Kozaky she not my legal guardian as she stays at my village. So I had to travel there and it takes some times. And I as her grandchild had a promise with her to handle her funeral. I'm not so sure about any of my officemates has applied leave other than parents and siblings.

Comment: @Twyxz what do you mean depends on location?

Comment: `I try to message to my manager to apply for bereavement leave but he stated that I'm not eligible to apply.`..so you are saying your manager is wrong..question is, are you sure? Why don't you check with someone else, someone from HR department, about whether there is any policy about the same? Whatever answer we provide here would not be authentic. It's not about fair or unfair, it's about what's in the agreement and company policy.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I did not say my manager is wrong but I'm not sure the exact terms to apply for that leave. I just want a confirmation. :)

Comment: @Nazrein But, you have a reason to believe 1) either your manager is wrong or 2) he is lying. Why is that (just asking...not that is has to do anything with the question, still)?

Comment: Bereavement leave applies to immediate family and in most countries that includes grandparents. I'd call someone at admin or HR in your company to get an official reply. You should be entitled to said leave. Then again, each company has its own policies so in this case, your company's policies might just include parents and siblings as part of that type of leave.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's still my fault for not asking why I'm not eligible for that leave. I'm still in a sad mood when I asked this from my manager. Maybe I'm too rushing with the decision and not asking more. :')

Comment: @Xander Yes. I think my company policies only include parents and siblings as for bereavement leaves. I will confirm with HR of my company about this. Thank you.

Comment: From a Belgian point of view: bereavement leave does not apply to grandparents (by default), only direct family (i.e. parents, siblings, children). Exceptions are made where the deceased is considered direct family, such as legal guardianship, living on the same official address, adoption, having been an official caretaker of the deceased, closest living relative, ...). In reality, most companies are almost inherently open to approving leave requests, but there's no legal provision for bereavement leave.

Comment: I voted to close as off topic since this (likely) depends on company policy. Check your company handbook or have HR give you a copy of the bereavement leave policy. I've certainly had employers where it included grandparents and others where it did not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry for your loss.

Unfortunately bereavement leave in Malaysia has no statutory entitlement - it's entirely at the discretion of the employer, and from the sounds of it their policy doesn't include grandparents. The fact that they are suggesting emergency leave might be a possibility is encouraging - it sounds as if the answer isn't a flat "no", rather that the logistics just need to be different.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I agree with you. Rather than no, I still able to apply for emergency leave. Thank you for clarifying your answer. :)

Comment: @Nazrein No problem - hope you feel better soon.